# How to add 1 cm thick line in the top and bottom of the page for the report

Tags: raise

Need to create a report in LaTeX with adding the the thick lines in the top and border of the pages

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{eso-pic,xcolor}
\begin{document}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
 \AtPageUpperLeft{%
 \textcolor{blue}{\rule[-0.5cm]{\paperwidth}{0.5cm}}}}
 \AtPageLowerLeft{%
 \textcolor{grey}{\rule[-0.5cm]{\paperwidth}{0.5cm}}}}
\flushleft
{\color{blue}
\LARGE{contents}\\
}
\flushleft
This is my first document for latex
\end{document}
```

This is the code I had given

but It is showing the error as while

You can't use `\raise; in vertical mode.

```
\put  (#1,#2)#3->\@killglue \raise 
                                   #2\unitlength \hb@xt@ \z@ {\kern #1\unitl...
l.12 ...{grey}{\rule[-0.5cm]{\paperwidth}{0.5cm}}}
                                                  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

See, if the following solution will work for you:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{eso-pic,xcolor}

\begin{document}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
 \AtPageUpperLeft{\color{blue}\rule[-0.5cm]{\paperwidth}{1cm}}
 \AtPageLowerLeft{\color{gray}\rule[-0.5cm]{\paperwidth}{1cm}}
                     }

\flushleft
{\color{blue}
\LARGE{contents}\\
}

This is my first document for latex
\end{document}
```

[image]

I use recent version of MikTeX installation. As you can see, my changes in your MWE (minimal Working Example is minor,  `textcolor{...}{...}` is replace by `\color{...}` and corrected is spelling error in color name.

*Note*, with your code the lines thick are 0.5cm thick, not 1cm, as is required in question's title. That the bottom lines can be seen (as 0.5cm thick), I increase lines' thickness to 1cm. However, for the 1cm thickness you should use in above MWE the following definition:

```
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
    \AtPageUpperLeft{\color{blue}\rule[-1cm]{\paperwidth}{1cm}}
    \AtPageLowerLeft{\color{gray}\rule{\paperwidth}{1cm}}
                     }
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much,  Now I  got the result, and Thanks for explaining the problem in the code very helpfull for me

Comment: @Tamil, meanwhile I add some more explanation and code example. If you find answer helpful, you can accept it (by clicking on check mar at top left side of answer :-)